# Qt (C++): Add background text in line edit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I want to be able to add a line of (grey) text that when you type in the line edit, goes away. So the text is not actually there, it is just displayed.

For example:
Before I type something, the grey background text is there:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U955.png

After I type something, the text goes away, replaced by the text entered:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXVAQ.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`void QLineEdit::setPlaceholderText( const QString & )`  [is what you are looking for:](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop)

Ex:

```
ui->lineEdit->setPlaceholderText(QString("Type here"));
```

[image]